# string collection user control property

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, custom-controls

I am creating a WPF User Control that needs to have a collection of strings as a property.  Currently I have the following code:

Variable declaration:

```
private List<string> lsInputNames = new List<string>();
```

Property accessors:

```
    [DisplayName("Input Names")]
    [Category("I/O")]
    public List<string> InputNames
    {
        get { return lsInputNames; }
        set
        {
            lsInputNames = value; 
        }
    }
```

When I hit the ellipsis under the "Input Names" property the Collection Editor comes up but everything is disabled.  How can I access this string collection property?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create some design time data?  What are you trying to do to the string collection?

Comment: I want to add and edit items in the collection.  The string collection itself will be used to display the input names on the user control.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound overdone, but why not just use a ViewModel for each control, and store these in a List instead of strings? Then you can just access the properties as needed.

Comment: I believe I am doing as you suggest. This is a list of type string. The problem that I am having is when I hit the ellipsis for the "Input Names" property I cannot edit the the list all is disabled.